# Inconsistency in grails command object validation

Tags: grails, grails-2.2, grails-validation

I have following command object with constraints :

```
@Validateable
class RefundCommand{
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RefundCommand.class)

    Double amount
    String order_id
    MerchantAccount merchant
    OrderReference order
    String unique_request_id

    public void getDerivedValues() {
        this.order = OrderReference.findByOrderIdAndMerchantId(order_id, merchant.merchantId)
    }

    static constraints = {
        amount nullable: false, validator: {amount, cmd->
          if(cmd.amount <= 0) {
                log.info("Amount must be greater than 0. Given value: ${cmd.amount}")
                return ['invalid.amount']
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Initiating an object in following way inside a controller:

```
def refund = {RefundCommand cmd->

    def String orderId = params.orderId
    def String merchantId = params.merchant.merchantId
    def Double amount = params.amount.toDouble()
    OrderReference orderReference = OrderReference.findByOrderIdAndMerchantId(orderId, merchantId)
    MerchantAccount merchantAccount = MerchantAccount.findByMerchantId(merchantId)
    cmd.order_id = orderId
    cmd.merchant = merchantAccount
    cmd.order = orderReference
    cmd.amount = amount
    cmd.unique_request_id = "rf_" + util.generateUniqueReference()
    cmd.clearErrors()
    cmd.validate()
    log.info(cmd.dump())
    if(cmd.hasErrors()) {
         ..... 
         return
    }
    proceedForRefund()
}
```

When I deploy initially validations are not working, validate() always return true and hasError() return null.

As we are using nginx, if I make any change in RefundCommand file then after auto-compile validation start working.

What could be the reason for that?

we are using grails-2.2.2 with nginx server.

Comment: First, forget about nginx and troubleshoot Grails. Make sure the validation is working consistently; every single time. THEN, and only then, introduce nginx. If the problem occurs only when nginx comes into play, then obviously nginx is doing something that's messing things up, and you'll need to troubleshoot that.

Comment: Issue is resolved now, we had @validateable with class & also "grails.validateable.classes" in  config.groovy...removing this class from config.groovy did the work.